Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. shadcn
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of ImageUpload.
components/ImageUpload.js
import React ,{ useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


import {
    Drawer,
    DrawerClose,
    DrawerContent,
    DrawerDescription,
    DrawerFooter,
    DrawerHeader,
    DrawerTitle,
    DrawerTrigger,
    Button
} from "../components/ui/drawer"

export default function ImageUpload() {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
    const [selectedFormat, setSelectedFormat] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [downloadLink, setDownloadLink] = useState('');

    const [loadng, setLoading] = useState('');


    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        setSelectedFile(file);
    };

    const handleFormatChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedFormat(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {

        setLoading(!loadng);


        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', selectedFile);
        formData.append('text', selectedFormat);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/image/', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            });
            setMessage('Image uploaded and converted successfully');
            setDownloadLink(response.data.converted_image_url); // Set download link
        } catch (error) {
            setMessage('Failed to upload and convert image');
        }
        finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    };

    const reset = () => {
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setDownloadLink('');
        setMessage('');
        setSelectedFormat('');
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className=''>
                <h1 className="tw-text-white tw-text-center tw-font-bold tw-text-2xl tw-mb-10">Image Conversion</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className=' xl:tw-w-1/2 lg:tw-w-9/12 tw-mx-auto tw-px-5'>


                    <div class="tw-flex tw-items-center tw-justify-center tw-w-full">
                        <label for="dropzone-file" class={`${!selectedFile ? 'tw-flex-col tw-h-64 tw-justify-center hover:tw-bg-yellow-300' : 'tw-bg-yellow-400 tw-h-20 tw-px-5'} tw-flex  tw-items-center  tw-w-full  tw-border-2 tw-border-white tw-border-dashed tw-cursor-pointer tw-bg-yellow-400 `}>
                            {/* <label for="dropzone-file" className="tw-px-5 tw-flex tw-items-center tw-w-full tw-h-20 tw-border-2 tw-border-gray-300 tw-border-dashed tw-rounded-lg tw-cursor-pointer tw-bg-gray-50 hover:tw-bg-gray-100"> */}
                            {!selectedFile ?
                                <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-items-center tw-justify-center tw-pt-5 tw-pb-6">
                                    <svg class="tw-w-8 tw-h-8 tw-mb-4 tw-text-black" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <p class="tw-mb-2 tw-text-sm tw-text-black"><span class="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                                    <p class="tw-text-xs tw-text-black">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX. 800x400px)</p>
                                </div> : null}
                            <h1 className='tw-text-black tw-font-semibold'>{selectedFile && selectedFile.name}</h1>
                            <input disabled={loadng || downloadLink ? true : false} id="dropzone-file" type="file" class="tw-hidden" accept='image/*' onChange={handleFileChange} />
                            {selectedFile ?
                                <div className='tw-w-full tw-flex tw-items-center tw-justify-end tw-gap-5'>
                                    {downloadLink ?
                                        <h1 className='tw-p-3 tw-px-5 tw-border-2 tw-border-black tw-font-bold tw-rounded-lg'>Done</h1>
                                        :
                                        <select value={selectedFormat} onChange={handleFormatChange} className='tw-py-3'>
                                            <option value="">Select format</option>
                                            <option value="png">PNG</option>
                                            <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
                                            <option value="jpeg">JPEG</option>
                                            <option value="webp">WEBP</option>
                                            <option value="bmp">BMP</option>
                                        </select>
                                    }
                                    {!selectedFile || !downloadLink ?
                                        <button disabled={loadng ? true : false} type='submit' className={`tw-transition-all tw-delay-100 tw-font-bold tw-bg-zinc-900
                             hover:tw-bg-zinc-800 hover:tw-border-dotted hover:tw-border-white hover:tw-border-2 tw-border-2
                              tw-border-zinc-900 tw-text-white tw-p-5 tw-rounded-xl tw-px-10 tw-flex hover:tw-text-yellow-300`}>
                                            {!loadng ? 'Convert' : <img src='/images/loading.svg' className='tw-invert' />}
                                        </button> : null}


                                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined material-symbols-outlined tw-text-black tw-font-bold
                                            hover:tw-text-white tw-text-3xl hover:tw-drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_black] tw-transition-all tw-delay-70">
                                        settings
                                    </span>


                                    <div className='tw-flex tw-gap-4 tw-items-center'>
                                        {downloadLink ?
                                            <a href={downloadLink} target='_blank' className='hover:tw-no-underline hover:tw-text-yellow-300 tw-transition-all tw-delay-100 tw-font-bold tw-bg-zinc-900
                             hover:tw-bg-zinc-800 hover:tw-border-dotted hover:tw-border-white hover:tw-border-2 tw-border-2
                              tw-border-zinc-900 tw-text-white tw-py-4 tw-rounded-xl tw-px-10 tw-flex'>Download</a>
                                            : null}
                                        <button href={'/'} onClick={reset}>
                                            <span title='Remove File' class="material-symbols-outlined tw-text-black tw-font-bold
                                            hover:tw-text-white tw-text-3xl hover:tw-drop-shadow-[0_5px_5px_black] tw-transition-all tw-delay-70">
                                                cancel
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                : null}
                        </label>
                    </div>





                    <p>{message}</p>
                    {downloadLink && (
                        <a href={downloadLink} download={downloadLink.split('/').pop()}>
                            Download Converted Image
                        </a>
                    )}
                </form>


            </div>
            <Drawer>
                <DrawerTrigger>Open</DrawerTrigger>
                <DrawerContent>
                    <DrawerHeader>
                        <DrawerTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</DrawerTitle>
                        <DrawerDescription>This action cannot be undone.</DrawerDescription>
                    </DrawerHeader>
                    <DrawerFooter>
                        <Button>Submit</Button>
                        <DrawerClose>
                            <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
                        </DrawerClose>
                    </DrawerFooter>
                </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>

        </>
    );
};



components/ui/drawer.js


import * as React from "react"
import { Drawer as DrawerPrimitive } from "vaul"

import { cn } from "../../lib/utils"

const Drawer = ({
  shouldScaleBackground = true,
  ...props
}) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Root shouldScaleBackground={shouldScaleBackground} {...props} />
)
Drawer.displayName = "Drawer"

const DrawerTrigger = DrawerPrimitive.Trigger

const DrawerPortal = DrawerPrimitive.Portal

const DrawerClose = DrawerPrimitive.Close

const DrawerOverlay = React.forwardRef(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Overlay
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("fixed inset-0 z-50 bg-black/80", className)}
    {...props} />
))
DrawerOverlay.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Overlay.displayName

const DrawerContent = React.forwardRef(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPortal>
    <DrawerOverlay />
    <DrawerPrimitive.Content
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        "fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-50 mt-24 flex h-auto flex-col rounded-t-[10px] border border-zinc-200 bg-white dark:border-zinc-800 dark:bg-zinc-950",
        className
      )}
      {...props}>
      <div
        className="mx-auto mt-4 h-2 w-[100px] rounded-full bg-zinc-100 dark:bg-zinc-800" />
      {children}
    </DrawerPrimitive.Content>
  </DrawerPortal>
))
DrawerContent.displayName = "DrawerContent"

const DrawerHeader = ({
  className,
  ...props
}) => (
  <div
    className={cn("grid gap-1.5 p-4 text-center sm:text-left", className)}
    {...props} />
)
DrawerHeader.displayName = "DrawerHeader"

const DrawerFooter = ({
  className,
  ...props
}) => (
  <div className={cn("mt-auto flex flex-col gap-2 p-4", className)} {...props} />
)
DrawerFooter.displayName = "DrawerFooter"

const DrawerTitle = React.forwardRef(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Title
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("text-lg font-semibold leading-none tracking-tight", className)}
    {...props} />
))
DrawerTitle.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Title.displayName

const DrawerDescription = React.forwardRef(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Description
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("text-sm text-zinc-500 dark:text-zinc-400", className)}
    {...props} />
))
DrawerDescription.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Description.displayName

export {
  Drawer,
  DrawerPortal,
  DrawerOverlay,
  DrawerTrigger,
  DrawerClose,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerTitle,
  DrawerDescription,
}


I am new to next.js. any help would be appreciated.
i am trying to use shandcn drawer component in my component. but getting the error when i click on the open button.
